# Error: The spawned process exited with non-zero exit code

Tags: oracle, odac

I am trying to install ODTwithODAC "Oracle Universal installer with Odac" for visual studio,so i could connect Oracle database with C# and i am getting this error:  "The spawned process exited with non-zero exit code!!". then the installation is not finished. 
any help to fix this please? 
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0Eiz.png)

Comment: please edit the question and provide more details - environment, etc.

Comment: @OldProgrammer 
Hi, hopefully it's now clear. I have added a screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot, the Oracle installer is trying to run the file Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0 and for some reason it is failing. You can manually navigate to the location of this file and try to run it. Based on your screenshot, that location is :

```
D:\app\tarek\product\18.0.0\client_1\odt\vs2017\Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0.vsix
```

If that fails, you can go directly to the Oracle site here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/developer-tools/visual-studio/ and download the version of Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio that matches the Visual Studio version you have installed.

Regardless of whether or if you choose to install the vsix package (although it is highly recommended as that's what the installer was trying to do), if you click on Continue, your installation of ODAC should complete without any further errors.